# Image of map induced by linear system of divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a conic section in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Then its ideal $I_K$ is generated by a linear form $L$ and a quadratic form $Q$. Let $L_i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$ be linear forms such that $L$ and $L_i$ are linearly independent. Then we can take $V(L^2)$, $V(LL_1)$, $V(LL_2)$, $V(LL_3)$, $V(Q)$ as a basis for the linear system of quadrics containing $K$. This gives rise to a map $\varphi \colon \mathbb{P}^3 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^4$ given by
$$
\varphi(p) = \left[L^2(p) : LL_1(p) : LL_2(p) : LL_3(p) : Q(p) \right].
$$
In [section 7.2.1 of Dolgachev](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/CAG.pdf) he writes that the image of $\varphi$ is contained in a quadric. I want to know what that quadric is.

My advisor said to let $L$ and $L_i$ be the coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $L^2$, $LL_i$, $Q$ the coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^4$. Then let $Q'$ be the quadratic form that defines $K$ when restricted to $V(L)$ and is such that it is independent of $L$, that is $Q'(L, L_1, L_2, L_3) = Q'(L_1, L_2, L_3)$. Then $Q'(LL_1, LL_2, LL_3) = L^2Q'(L_1, L_2, L_3)$ defines a quadric in $\mathbb{P}^4$ containing $\varphi(\mathbb{P}^3)$, but I am having difficulty seeing why this is so.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity's sake, let $L = x, L_1 = y, L_2 = z, L_3 = w$. So the conic section lies in the $x = 0$ plane.

Now the space of quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^3$ has basis $\{x^2,y^2,z^2,w^2, xy, xz, xw, yz, yw, zw\}$. By your setup, we choose the subspace of quadrics containing the conic section $V(Q)\cap V(x)$ with basis $\mathbf{B} := \{x^2, xy, xz, xw, Q\}$. Note that this means $Q$ must be some linear combination of $\mathbf{C} := \{y^2, z^2, w^2, yz, yw, zw\}$. i.e. $Q$ is a linear combination of the quadratic monomials *not* containing $x$ as a factor. Now to see that the image of your rational map is contained in a quadric, we need to show that your basis satisfies a quadratic relation in the coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^4$.

Now consider the quartic polynomial $x^2Q$. It is a linear combination $F$ of quartic monomials of the form $\{x^2s : s \in \mathbf{C}\}$. But it takes very little effort to see that this set of quartic monomials is exactly equal to the set $\{pq : p,q \in \mathbf{B}\setminus\{x^2,Q\}\}$. Hence, thinking now of $\mathbf{B}$ as coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^4$ (as your advisor suggested) you can see that $x^2Q - F$ is a quadratic relation in those coordinates which is satisfied by everything in the image of your rational map. So $\varphi(\mathbb{P}^3) \subset V(x^2Q - F)$, the latter of which is a quadric in $\mathbb{P}^4$.